# Como fazer upload de arquivos?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Bem amigos, tenho que fazer o upload de arquivos pdf (e somente nesse formato) e vincular a um usuário. Como eu poderia fazer isso? Qual é a melhor forma de estruturar os arquivos salvos no servidor?

Comment: Existem algumas gems que resolvem este problema: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_file_uploads